# unable to write to/read from file

Tags: c++

The code I wrote seems to work when i write data in the file but when i look into the record.dat file after writing into it, it shows nothing. The segment with "Main Menu" gets repeated from the switch() every time i try to read from the file. I had to write the open commands with the access modes separately inside each case otherwise it wouldn't even open the file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

class employee
{
private:
  int empcode;
  char empname[30];
  char empdesig[15];
  float empsalary;
public:
  void add_rec()
  {
    cout<<"\nEmployee Code : ";
    cin>>empcode;
    cout<<"\nEmployee Name : ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(empname,30);
    cout<<"\nEmployee Designation : ";
    cin.getline(empdesig,15);
    cout<<"\nEmployee Salary : ";
    cin>>empsalary;
  }
  void read_rec()
  {
    cout<<"\nEmployee Code : "<<empcode;
    cout<<"\nEmployee Name : "<<empname;
    cout<<"\nEmployee Designation : "<<empdesig;
    cout<<"\nEmployee Salary : "<<empsalary;
  }
};
int main()
{
  employee emp;
  fstream rfile;
  int ch,rec_no=0,pos=0;
  char ans='y',opt;
  do
  {
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"\t\t\t MAIN MENU ";
    cout<<"\n1. Add Record ";
    cout<<"\n2. Read Record ";
    cout<<"\n3. Modify Record ";
    cout<<"\n4. Exit "<<endl;
    cout<<"\nSelect an option : ";
    cin>>ch;
    switch (ch)
    {
      case 1:
            {
              rfile.open("record.dat", ios::out);
              char opt='y';
              cout<<"\t\t\tEmployee Data Entry "<<endl;
              do
              {
                emp.add_rec();
                rfile.write((char*)&emp,sizeof(emp));
                cout<<"\nEnter another record ? {Y/N} ";
                cin>>opt;
              } while(opt=='y'||opt=='Y');
            }
            break;
      case 2:
            {
              rfile.open("record.dat", ios::in);
              cout<<"\t\t\tEmployee Data Display "<<endl;
              rfile.read((char*)&emp,sizeof(emp));
              while(rfile)
              {
                emp.read_rec();
                rfile.read((char*)&emp,sizeof(emp));
              }
            }
            break;
      case 3:
            {
              rfile.open("record.dat", ios::out);
              cout<<"\t\t\tEmployee Data Modify "<<endl;
              cout<<"\nEnter the record no. to modify : ";
              cin>>rec_no;
              pos=(rec_no-1)*sizeof(emp);
              rfile.seekg(pos,ios::beg);
              rfile.read((char*)&emp,sizeof(emp));
              cout<<"\nModify this record ? {Y/N} "<<endl;
              cin>>opt;
              if(opt=='y'||opt=='Y')
              {
                cout<<"\n";
                cout<<"\t\t\tEnter New Data "<<endl;
                emp.add_rec();
                rfile.write((char*)&emp,sizeof(emp));
                cout<<"\nRecord Modified"<<endl;
                cout<<"\nPress any key to continue...";
                getch();
              }
            }
            break;
      case 4:
            break;
      default:
            cout<<"\nPlease select a valid option!";
            break;
    }
  } while(ch!=4);
  rfile.close();
  return(0);
}
```

Comment: The file gets wiped when you open it for writing, so make sure you aren't opening it again after you write to it.

Comment: Also, your code is confusing. In case 1 for example, you have an if statement with no brackets. Is `char opt='y'` supposed to happen when the file isn't opened properly? That wouldn't make sense as you are using that condition to write to the file later, which you wouldn't want to do if it doesn't exist...

Comment: i forgot to delete the if statement...that was suposed to check if the file was actually opening or not and display an error message..which i did not require later

Comment: Well, theres a lot going on here and your code spacing is hard to read. If you want more help please work through your code and delete everything that's unecessary to the problem (couts, extra functions/if statements) in order to make a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @amstrudy ... a [mcve]. There is a [magic link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000) for this: `[mcve]` for your convenience. (`mcve` because in the past it expanded to Minimal Complete Verifiable Example. The title changed recently - don't know why but it's surely mentioned in Meta somewhere.) ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you open a file for writing under a case statement, you also need to close the file. When the file is closed, the double buffered values are then written to the physical file.

Under case 1, add a file close after the while statement:
} while(opt=='y'||opt=='Y');
rfile.close();

Make similar updates to case 2 and 3, and both case 1 and 2 will now work. Case 3 has additional issues. For example, when opening the file to modify, you will want to use the "app" bit mask so you do not delete existing contents. See the following for more information:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open